# I can't click on top menus

Tags: menus

I have started using Wordpress 5 days ago. First question over here :)

I have this website [aimygod.pt](http://aimygod.pt) and the top menu isn't clickable with the left mouse button. The only way I can open the page `categorias` is through `right click -> open in a new tab`.

You can check through the source code that the `<a href="aibonito.pt/categorias/"> Categorias </a>` is over there.

Comment: There's some JS errors which are probably causing the issue. Start by disabling all your plugins - then going to the default theme to narrow down what could be causing it.

Comment: I have no plugin installed. I'm using the theme `videotouch` by `ThemeForest`. Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: If you purchased the theme from Theme Forest, they should be able to support any issues you're having with the theme - that would be your best bet as I doubt you're the only person who's had issues with it.

Comment: I did sed them a ticket but it's been more than a week and they didn't respond yet.

Comment: "it's been more than a week and they didn't respond yet" Contact ThemeForest and file a complaint - these cowboys need to be held accountable.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic I'll wait one more day. I'm dying right here trying to solve the problem on my on. I have no experience with hard coding. Just some simple programs. This right here is quite difficult for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is offtopic, but since I'm in a good mood with the weekend coming up I'll answer you anyway ;-)

The problem is there because the menu you have chosen to use on the page is meant for links that scroll down on the same page. Therefore a piece of javascript is included by the theme that disables normal link behaviour in favour of scrolling. But since the link is not to another place on the page the javascript can't scroll anywhere and nothing happens.

As far as I can see Videotouch has a whole bunch of possible menus. Just try one that is meant for external links.

Comment: Thank you cjbj for your answer. Much appreciated. I have only one menu, the one that came with the theme. This problem started after I changed the page `/homepage/` to become the front page at the `Settings -> Reading`. I didn't remember touching the `menu` tab.

Comment: Sorry, since I don't know what your theme does, I can only look at the resulting page, which shows that the menu has a class that triggers the scrollling javascript code.